# How to set timeout to RestServiceAdapter in Oracle MAF?

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-maf, maf

I am using RestServiceAdapter in Oracle MAF to call Restfull Services, I want to set a timeout for the service due to I having issuess when there is network connections (for example: low signal, wrong access point connected, etc) so the application goes weird, it tries to do the request and then hang out with weird behaveior.

this is my code which is working great but I would to throw an Exception if it is taking longer more than some X seconds.

```
public String getJSONResponse(String baseUrlService) throws Exception {
    try {
        RestServiceAdapter restServiceAdapter = RestServiceAdapterFactory.newFactory().createMcsRestServiceAdapter();  
        restServiceAdapter.clearRequestProperties();  
        restServiceAdapter.setConnectionName(REST_STORE_CONNECTION);  
        restServiceAdapter.setRequestURI(baseUrlService);       
        restServiceAdapter.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //Base 64 de Autenticacion de Weblogic real usuario 'Basic store-rest-user:password'
        restServiceAdapter.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + loginBase64);
        //restServiceAdapter.setRequestType(RestServiceAdapter.REQUEST_TYPE_GET);  
        String response = restServiceAdapter.send(""); 
        return response;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error: problema de conexión o problema en servidor");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no option in the RestServiceAdapter to timeout a connectivity. But you can configure how often to retry a connection.  So the best practice seems to be to set retry limit to 1 and then access the remote service from a background thread using the RestServiceAdapter.

Comment: Thank you, actually I was trying to send in a background service and time out this using Executors, I think I achieve something but it is getting complicated to do something that it is suppose to be easy. I will try what you said.

Comment: If you find it right, please upvote the answer. It will be useful for others

Comment: I consider it useful but it does not solve the need to timeout the request

Comment: if you want to use setTimedOut use HttpURLConnection